# Postscript name of San Francisco font

Tags: font

I'm using MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. I want to change the system font on my MacBook Air. I know (or think) that the system recognises fonts using the postscript name of the font. I know that below Mac OSX Yosemite, the name is `.LuciadaGrandeUI` and for Mac OSX Yosemite, the name is `.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular`. However, above Mac OSX Yosemite, the font is San Francisco. What is the postscript name of the font?

EDIT:

Actual problem: I want to change the system font to Comic Sans MS. How?

Comment: This seems very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Rather than ask about how to do what you think might be how to solve your issue, why not ask about your actual issue? See https://osxdaily.com/2018/11/16/lucida-grande-system-font-macos-mojave/

Comment: i want to use comic sans

Comment: Oh dear… then there's little more I can say.

Comment: Does it work on Catalina?